# Do I need a medical exam for an IEC Canada work permit?

Tags: canada

I am applying for a Work permit for the IEC to go to Canada, I do not fall under any of the jobs on the list that require a medical but I am going for over 6 months, do I need a medical? I have lived in the UK all my life.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't, according to the [Government of Canada Medical exam requirements for temporary residents (visitors, students and workers)](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/medexams-temp.asp) (emphasis mine):

> **If you plan to visit for more than six months:** 
>   You will need a medical exam if *you have lived temporarily for six or more consecutive months*
>
> - in one or more of [these countries or territories](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/dcl.asp)
> - in the one year immediately before the date you want to enter Canada. (This applies even if you are a citizen of a country that does not need a visa to enter Canada.)

It is a bit of an awkward construct which takes more than one read. More directly:

1. You will need a medical exam if you have lived in [one of these countries.](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/dcl.asp)

**OR**

2. During the year before you enter Canada, you will stay in one of [those countries](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/medical/dcl.asp) without leaving for at least six months (or more).